# How to mask or remove display password in admin page?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want users of the admin tool to be able to view the password when a user clicks the reset button. How to masked or removed plain text password from the same page. Usually, the system sends link to user's email and after clicking on that email only they can change their password.

```
<p class="para"> Login page </P> 
<input name="action" type="hide">
<input name="target" type="hide">
<input name="id" type="hide">
<input name="targetId" type="hide" value="12345">
<table border="0" cellpading="5" ellspacing="0">

<input name="resetPassword" onClick="resetPassword"('12345')" type="button" value="reset Password">
```

At this scenario how to hide or remove displayed plain text password?

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the browser to begin with, you can't. Even if you change the text field to type **password**, it's trivial in Chrome to change it back to text and see the password.

The new password should be handled by the server, not the browser client.